# Getting the physical shape of screen curves, corners and cutouts

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

How can I get information about the rounded screen corners on eg the Galaxy S8 and Pixel 2 XL?
I know `WindowInsets` was added in Android KitKat Wear API 20, so developers could know about the 'flat tyre' cutout on the Moto 360. But it only contains integer offsets from each edge. Bottom insets are always 0 in my testing on a S8 with corners (when bottom nav bar is hidden).

I see the Android P Developer preview adds a `DisplayCutout` to this class, with a `Region` and `Path`. Documentation says this is for cutouts like Essential's notch. Does the new `DisplayCutout` also include information about the Pixel 2 XL's corners? Could someone with a Pixel and the developer preview confirm this?

If I resize my app to a floating window (ie picture-in-picture), then move the window so a corner or notch intrudes on it, will I get a `onApplyWindowInsets` with new `DisplayCutout` info?

What about information about the curved edge screen on Galaxy S8, S9 etc? I guess `DisplayCutout` does not add information about this, and I would need a database with this info instead? We won't be able to confirm this until `P` arrives on S9, in mid 2019(?) or so.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a few updates:

- The `Path` was removed from subsequent `P` Developer Previews, but has resurfaced 3 years later in the `S` Developer Preview: [`DisplayCutout.getCutoutPath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DisplayCutout#getCutoutPath())
- Android `R` added [`DisplayCutout.getWaterfallInsets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/DisplayCutout#getWaterfallInsets()) to get "the insets representing the curved areas of a waterfall display"
- The `S` Developer Preview also adds a `RoundedCorner` API, via [`WindowInsets.getRoundedCorner(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets?hl=en#getRoundedCorner(int)). It provides the center point and radius of each rounded corner. Ref: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features#rounded_corner_apis